# Active Directory operation timeout limit exceeded on one DC, but not on another

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm using the following script to get all the active users in AD.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Domain Users" |
    Where {$_.Enabled -eq $true} | select * |
    Export-Csv AD.csv -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

I'm getting a timeout:

> Error: Get-ADGroupMember : The operation returned because the timeout limit was exceeded

There are only 3000 users in AD, I was able to get the report from one server but from another one I get this error.

Comment: maybe you'll find your answer in here: [social technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/b5b439fe-1aa9-4823-a3ac-d0be643a5073/query-using-ad-module-timed-out)

Answer (score 1):

This might be of help to you. I was starting to get time-out errors on large security groups when using `Get-ADGroupMember` so I had to revert to using an LDAP query:

```
$Group = [ADSI]"LDAP://$($G.DistinguishedName)"
$Members = $Group.PSBase.Invoke('Members') | ForEach-Object {
    $_.GetType().InvokeMember('samaccountname','GetProperty',$null,$_,$null)
}
```